# "This site can't be reched" the connection was reset with WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Apologies if this is the wrong area, so any advice to the correct location would be great.

Symptoms:

When connecting to WCF service in Vivaldi (this uses the chrome rendering engine) you get:

This site can’t be reached

> The connection was reset.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the
>
> proxy and the firewall Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Or in the case of Firefox you are redirected to a search engine to find the domain.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while and this is how I found what the issue was.

1. Install the Windows SDK, this will install a very useful tool to help configure web.config for WCF services.
2. Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\SvcConfigEditor.exe"
3. Go to File | New to create a new config, or File | Open to existing config file.
4. From the services node, you can create new/edit services
5. Scroll down to the "Diagnostics" node and click on "Message Logging" and set the following items to true: "LogEntireMessage" if you want known personally identifiable information is logged then set "LogKnownPii" to true
6. Now click "End to End Tracing" and set "ActivityTracing" and "MessageFlowTracing" to true.
7. Right click on "Listeners" and create a ServiceModelMessageLogginListner and ServiceModelTraceListner for both the init data is where you want the logs to be written to.
8. On the Source node right click and create a new source, from the drop-down select the lisetner(s) created in step #7. Select the debug level
9. Save the changes, reset IIS (just to make sure IIS picks the changes up) and follow the URL.
10. Once you have reproduced the error navigate to the location you specified in step #7 there you will find a file with the extension of .svclog, this is a plain text XML file, then in the same location as the SvcConfigEditor there is another application called "SvcTraceViewer" this allows you to view the log without paging through the entire xml file.

Here is an example web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <!--Start of System Diagnostics-->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Off,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="NewListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="E:\Projects\C#\home-intranet-webservice\HomeIntranetService\Web_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="E:\Projects\C#\home-intranet-webservice\HomeIntranetService\Web_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <!--End System Diagnostic Settings-->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Images" value="E:\Projects\Web\home-intranet-website\img"/>
    <add key="PageFragments" value="E:\Projects\Web\home-intranet-website\PageFragments"/>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="false"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
        messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="Documentation" helpEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="HomeIntranetService.Services.ComputersAndLicences">
        <endpoint address="../ComputersAndLicences.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="HomeIntranetService.Interfaces.IComputersAndLicences"
          kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="Documentation" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>     
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>

  </system.webServer>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```